# How to check for tooltip message on mouse hover in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, mousehover

I want to do mouseover function over Tooltip, which displays meessage.

Here is the link to video - https://screenrec.com/share/5IWTd4a7i9

For some reason hover does not happen due to which I do not get the text and test fails

This is what I have tried

```
browser.actions()
.mouseMove(
  element(by.xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/main/ng-component/ngb-tabset/div/div/view-concepts-tab/div[1]/concept-view/div/dl/mat-accordion/mat-expansion-panel/div/div/div[4]/term-view/div/div[3]/div[1]/dl/mat-accordion/mat-expansion-panel/mat-expansion-panel-header/span[1]/mat-panel-description/dd/span')))
.click()
.perform();

text('On mouse hover')
```

Also tried

```
    expect(element.all(by.xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/main/ng-component/ngb-tabset/div/div/view-concepts-tab/div/concept-view/div/dl/mat-accordion/mat-expansion-panel/div/div/div[2]/term-view/div/div[3]/div[1]/dl/mat-accordion/mat-expansion-panel/mat-expansion-panel-header/span[1]/mat-panel-description/dd/span'))).toEqual('On mouse hover');
```

**EDIT**

I got some success with below code, however error is     `Expected [  ] to equal 'On mouse hover'.`

```
    expect(element.all(by.css('dd#A>span'))).toEqual('On mouse hover');
```

Comment: Very tough to debug given there is no HTML structure to work with. However in your expect statement, you are comparing an element with a text. First get the text then match it with the text you want to match.

Comment: @demouser123 can you help write example code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use atribute value of title then you will get the tooltip text. you dont have to scroll to the element.

expect(element(By.id("xyz")).getAttribute("title")).ToBe("Tool tip text");

Comment: It says `Failed: By.id(...).getAttribute is not a function`

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Please try this. expect(element(By.id("xyz")).getAttribute("title")).ToBe("Tool tip text");

Comment: It says `By.id(...).getAttribute is not a function
`

Comment: Hi Ketan any other suggestion?

Comment: I have updated the my answer given. It was bracket closure issue. Can you please check once again.